# How to call this kind of implementation in Java and how to change it to C#?

Tags: c#, java

I have this piece of code:

```
protected class A 
{ 
  protected void call1(); 
  protected void call2(); 
}

public class B
{
   protected A a = new A() 
   {
      protected void call1(//modify);
   }
}
```

Also, how can I translate this:

```
protected A a = new A() 
{
  protected void call1(//modify);
;
```

to C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're after inheritance?

```
public class B : A
{
   protected override void call1()
   {
      //new code here...
   }
}
```

Comment: yes, it is something with inheritance but I dont know would it be possible to initialize an instance of a as: A a = new A {}?

Comment: @Joe yes in C# you can have: `A a = new A();` and `B b = new B();` in addition you can have `A b = new B();` since B is also A.

Comment: No that's illegal syntax unless you mean something like `A a = new A { prop1 = '1', prop2 = '2' };`?